# One part of the proof of $\sup(A\cup B)=\max\{\sup A, \sup B\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let

\begin{align*}
x\in A\cup B &\implies x \in A \text{ or } x\in B \\
&\implies x\leq \sup(A) \text{ or } x\leq \sup(B) \\
&\implies x\leq \max\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\}.
\end{align*}

I don't  know why it implies $\sup(A\cup B)\leq \max\{\sup A, \sup B\}$.

Comment: You have proved that $\max \{\sup(),\sup()\}$ is an upper bound for $A\cup B$. What can you say about its least upper bound?

Comment: You don't mention the "ambient set". Is it the real numbers, the rational numbers...?

Answer (score 1):

What you have showed is that for any $x\in A\cup B$ it holds that

$$x\leq \max\{\sup A,\sup B\}.$$

This means that $\max\{\sup A,\sup B\}$ is an upper bound of $A\cup B$. Now by definition, $\sup(A\cup B)$, is the smallest upper bound, meaning that it firstly is an upper bound, i.e. that

$$x\leq \sup(A\cup B)$$

for any $x\in A\cup B$, and that it is smaller than any other upper bound, i.e. that

$$\sup(A\cup B)\leq \max\{\sup A,\sup B\}.$$

Combining these we get that for all $x\in A\cup B$,

$$x\leq \sup(A\cup B)\leq \max\{\sup A,\sup B\}.$$

Comment: Thank you! I understand now

Answer (score 1):

We know $\max\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\}$ is an upper bound

WLOG let $\sup(A)<\sup(B)$ then we know

$\exists$ $\epsilon >0$ for some $x\in B$ such that $\sup(B)-\epsilon\leq x<\sup(B)\;\;\dots(1)$

Since $B\subset A\cup B$ the $(1)$ is true for $A\cup B$

Hence $\max\{\sup(B),\sup(B)\}=\sup(A\cup B)$